# Adding to dictionary keys

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm trying to create a running leaderboard in which each person starts with one point and I add to the key if they accomplish something. I'm not certain a dictionary is the best way to do it so recommendations are definitely welcomed.

I tried a list to begin with but a dictionary seemed to better suit my needs as I had lists inside of lists

```
myDict = {'person1' : 1 , 'person2' : 1 , 'person3' : 1}
```

If person1 were to do something i'd like their key to change to 2. I need to increment the keys, not assign a specific key. Also I will continually add entries to the dict for which I need their default value to be 1.

edit: Chris had a super helpful suggestion to use collections.defaultdict so that calling key that isn't in a dict adds it instead of returning a keyerror

Comment: You can assign to specific elements with `myDict["person1"] = 2`

Comment: Have you tried `myDict['person1'] += 1`?

Comment: @Chris I have not, I wasn't sure if that was a thing I could do and I couldn't figure out how to search it

Comment: IMO, `dict` is indeed the way to go. Everytime you got a winner, e.g. `winner = competition(some_jobs)`, use it as a key and do inplace add: `myDict[winner] += 1`

Comment: @Chris if the entry didn't exist would it create it? or will this just increment existing keys?

Comment: In such a case, one way is to use `collections.defaultdict`. Besides, please update such constraints to your question. Discussing lengthy in the comments is not really recommended :)

Comment: I want to point to class `collections.Counter` which looks close to your need. It has a default for a new person but counts from 0, not 1, and I think it's more intuitive. You will get method `Counter.most_common(n)`  for free which gives you top n persons in your competition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A value can be added or changed or reassigned in a python dictionary by simply accessing through it's key

```
myDict[key] = value
```

In your case:

```
myDict["person1"] = 2   # Reassignment or changing
myDict["person1"] += 1  # Increementing
```

If the key doesn't exist, incrementing will be a problem. In that scenario, you need to check if the key is present or not.

```
if myDict["person5"]:
    myDict["person5"] += 1
else:
    myDict["person5"] = 1
```

Reference https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries

Answer (score 0):

You can update a dictionary as follows:

```
>>> myDict = {'person1': 1, 'person2': 1}
>>> myDict['person7'] = 2
```

You may also want to investigate

```
import collections
myDict = collections.defaultdict(lambda: 1)
myDict['person7'] += 1
```

as this will automatically initialize unset values to `1` the first time they are read.

Comment: I need to increment it, not assign a specific value, got it though

Answer (score 0):

Unless you want to do something like sorting players by scores at the end, a dictionary seems a good option. (You can do the sorting but have to have a workaround since dictionary is only indexed by its keys)

Otherwise you can do the following to update the scores

```
myDict = {}
person = '<person_name>'
# in case the person did something
if person in myDict:
    myDict[person] += 1
else:
    myDict[person] = 1
```